# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in "package name"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, servlets

I am new to spring and hibernate  as well as to stackoverflow
A developing ecommerce project using spring hibernate maven 
creating two file one for frontend and 2nd for backend after creating two file i am adding dependency of backend into frontend pom.ml file

I am using java to create sessionfactory ,datasource and transaction manager 
here is the code I dont understand what mistake i am doing

```
package com.ecom.Config;


import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean; 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource; 
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder;
import 
org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.ecom.Model.CustomerRegistration;



 @Configuration
 @ComponentScan("com.ecom")
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 public class AnnotationConfigApplicationContext {

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource getH2DataSource() {

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/Ecommerce");

    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");

    dataSource.setUsername("sa");

    dataSource.setPassword("");

    return dataSource;
}


private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
    return properties;
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name = "sessionFactory")
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {

    LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sessionBuilder = new 
LocalSessionFactoryBuilder(dataSource);
    sessionBuilder.addProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    sessionBuilder.addAnnotatedClass(CustomerRegistration.class);


    return sessionBuilder.buildSessionFactory();
}

@Autowired
@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager(SessionFactory 
sessionFactory) {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new 
 HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);

    return transactionManager;
}



}
```

Contoller

```
 package com.ecom.Controller;


 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.ui.Model;

 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;

 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

 import com.ecom.DAO.CustomerRegDAO;
 import com.ecom.Model.CustomerRegistration;






@Controller
public class CustomerRegController
{
 @Autowired     
 private CustomerRegDAO  customerRegDAO ;   

 @RequestMapping("/registrationForm")
 public String Registration(Model theModel)
 {
     CustomerRegistration theCustomerRegistration = new 
CustomerRegistration();

     theModel.addAttribute("customer", theCustomerRegistration);

     return "registration-form";
 }

 @RequestMapping("/saveCustomer")
 public String saveCustomer(@ModelAttribute("customer")  
CustomerRegistration theCustomerRegistration)
 {

     customerRegDAO.saveCustomer(theCustomerRegistration);

     return "index";
 }  


 }
```

DAO

```
      package com.ecom.DAOImplementation;

     import javax.transaction.Transactional;

     import org.hibernate.Session;
     import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
     import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

     import com.ecom.DAO.CustomerRegDAO;
    import com.ecom.Model.CustomerRegistration;

  @Repository("CustomerRegDAO")
  @Transactional
  public class CustomerRegDAOImpl implements CustomerRegDAO {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

  @Transactional
  public void saveCustomer(CustomerRegistration theCustomerRegistration) {

    Session currentsession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    currentsession.saveOrUpdate(theCustomerRegistration);

   } 

  }
```

Error:

```
  Type Exception Report

  Message Servlet.init() for servlet [spring] threw exception

  Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented 
 it from fulfilling the request.

 Exception

 javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [spring] threw 
 exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase
.java:475)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogVa
lve.java:651)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)

 Root cause
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating 
 bean 
 with name 'sessionFactory' defined in 
 com.ecom.Config.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: Bean instantiation via 
 factory method failed; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate 
 [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: Factory method 'getSessionFactory' threw 
 exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not 
 initialize class 
 org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager

 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class 
 org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
```

Comment: Is your driver jar in classpath , dependencies added in maven ..

Answer (score 0):

The exception is indicating that the class `JavaReflectionManager` is not found. This class is present in `hibernate-commons-annotations` jar file. Can you add this in your `pom.xml` and try running it again?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I got the solution                                                                                 Hibernate annotation module is merged into Hibernate core module since v3.5. In this case, Hibernate is detected two annotation modules, from both “Hibernate core” and “Hibernate annotation“, causing conflict and prompt the ClassCastException. Reference: http://in.relation.to/2010/10/14/hibernate-core-360-final-release/

hibernate-annotations and hibernate-commons-annotations are not required, when we have hibernate-core dependency in the pom file.